# Firestore get last 24 hours documents from collection - Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get the documents which comes under last 24 hours, for each document I have set a field `timestamp` as:

```js
admin.firestore().collection('users').set({..., timestamp: new Date().toJSON() })
```

Now, in my cloud function, I want to get the docs which comes under last 24 hours only, so for that I came up with the logic:

```js
const end = new Date();
const start = new Date(end.getTime() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); // 24 hours ago

const users = await admin
                .firestore()
                .collection('users')
                .where('timestamp', '>', start)
                .where('timestamp', '<', end)
                .get();
```

But this returns nothing.

I also tried this question which was asked earlier: [Firebase query data of last 24 hour return same result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71538167/11685381)

```js
const users = await admin
                .firestore()
                .collection('users')
                .startAt(start)
                .get();
```

But it resulted in the following error:

```js
ERROR Error: Too many cursor values specified. The specified values must match the orderBy() constraints of the query.
```

So, can someone help me out here?

Thanks in advance!

(Do I have to change how I save `timestamp` in firestore? like instead of `timestamp: new Date().toJSON()` something else...?)

**EDIT-1**:

[image]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of a document in the Firebase console that you'd expected to be returned by the query?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi, I have added, please tell me if this is okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `timestamp` field in your database is stored as a string value, you also have to pass string values for conditions on that field:

```
admin
.firestore()
.collection('users')
.where('timestamp', '>', start.toJSON())
.where('timestamp', '<', end.toJSON())
```

Without that you're comparing strings and dates, and no value will every meet the condition in that case.